# Are the following functions also surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, applications

Let $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a surjective function. Assume that $f'$ is also surjective. Assume also that $f$ vanishe on $s=1$ of order $m$.

My **question** is: Are the following functions also surjective? 
 $$f(s^2-s+1)$$ and $$(s-1)f(s)$$

At least locally near the point $s=1$.

Comment: Can you just clarify what it the term "order $m$" means.

Comment: @MustafaSaid: $m$ is the order of vanishing of $f$ at $s=1$. This mean that $f$ vanishe and $f'$,...vanishe at $s=1$ but the $m$-th derivative does not vainshe on $s=1$.

Comment: Your last sentence "at least locally near the point $s=1$" does not make sense. If $f(s)$ vanishes at $s=1$, then certainly $(s-1)f(s)$ is close to $0$ near $s=1$.

Comment: I am wondering if you are really dealing with complex analysis, and you mean "poles" rather than "zeros," and you are dealing with Picard's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem In that case you really need to edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since $s^2 - s + 1 \geq 0$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$, the answer to the first question is "no."  That is because $f(s)$ might only be surjective because of its properties on negative values of $s$. (You can come up with a specific example).

2) The idea here is to construct a function $f(s)$ that is surjective over $s \in \mathbb{R}$, is *not* surjective over $s\geq 2$, but has a surjective derivative over $s\geq 2$.

Specifically, to show that $(s-1)f(s)$ is not necessarily surjective, even when $f(s)$ meets the criteria, define:
$f(s) = g(s)$ if $s \in [2, \infty)$
$f(s) = c(s)$ if $s \in [0,2]$
$f(s) = s-1$ if $s \in (-\infty, 0]$

where $g(s)$ has derivatives of all orders over $s\geq 2$, is non-negative for all $s \geq 2$, and satisfies $\sup_{s\geq 2}g'(s) = \sup_{s\geq 2}g(s) = \infty$ and $\inf_{s\geq 2} g'(s) = -\infty$.  You can come up with such a function $g(s)$.  Then fill in $c(s)$ appropriately over $s \in [0,2]$ to ensure the differentiability and $s=1$ conditions are met.  Finally, show that $f(s)$ is surjective, $f'(s)$ is surjective, but $\inf_{s\in \mathbb{R}} (s-1)f(s) > -\infty$.